# Pyspark Pipeline Custom Transformer

Tags: pyspark, transformer-model

I'm having some trouble understanding the creation of custom transformers for  Pyspark pipelines.

I am writing a custom transformer that will take the dataframe column `Company` and remove stray commas:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

class DFCommaDropper(Transformer):

    def__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = CommaDropper

    def transform(self,df):
        df = df.withColumn('Company', regexp_replace('Company',',','')
        return df
```

The above code is obviously wrong.  I'm unsure what/how to initialize this and then how to use the initialized class instance in the transform function.

Thanks in advance for your help.,